# Implicit conversion with multiple intermediate conversion steps

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I wonder weather it is possible in C++ for the compiler to infer a series of conversions from one starting type to an target type? In the example below there is a implicit conversion

- from `class a` to `class b`
- from `class b` to `cont char *`

However the compiler doesnt seem to try to infer a implicit conversion that would imply multiple conversion steps, in the below example from `class a` to `const char *`. In the below example the `cout << x` would return an error.

```
/*g++ -g -std=c++14 file.cpp -o file.exe
 * file.cpp:
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class b {
public:
  b(const char *n) : n(n) {};
  operator const char *() const {
    return n;
  }
  const char *n;
};

class a {
public:
  a(const char *n) : n(n) {};
  operator b() const {
    return b(n);
  }
  const char *n;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  a x("hello");
  b y = x;
  std::string z = (const char*)y;
  std::cout << y;
  std::cout << (b)x;
  //std::cout << x; would fail                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You only get **one** user defined conversion.

Comment: I would like to know weather there is a way to make the compiler do a implicit conversion chain. Maybe using templating or something...